# Exec Procedure Mysql with EF net core

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-core, stored-procedures

I try to execute a stored procedure with the following function, but the table is not updated and it does not show me an error,could you help me

```cs
public static void UpdateShareDate(string Sharepath, string ShareDate, int TransactionID, int Clientid)
{
    try
    {
        using (var context = new AppDBContext())
        {
            MySqlConnector.MySqlParameter[] queryParams = new MySqlConnector.MySqlParameter[] {
                    new MySqlConnector.MySqlParameter("@p1", Sharepath),
                    new MySqlConnector.MySqlParameter("@p2", ShareDate),
                    new MySqlConnector.MySqlParameter("@p3", TransactionID),
                    new MySqlConnector.MySqlParameter("@p4", Clientid)
                };

            string store_pocedure = "call MediaFile_Update(@p1,@p2,@p3,@p4)";
    var result = context.DBSetMediaFiles.FromSqlRaw(store_pocedure, queryParams);

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share `MediaFile_Update`.

Comment: You're actually not executing the query. Add `.ToList()` after `FromSqlRaw(...)`

Comment: Does database have a primary key?  Update will not work if a primary keys exists in database and the key is already in the database.  You then need to use Insert for new keys and update for existing keys.

Comment: Please update the store procedure too.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do in this case to see what is happening in DbContext level, I will enable logging like below,

1. add logging like below in your dbcontext,

   public static readonly ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory(new[] {
   new ConsoleLoggerProvider((_, __) => true, true)
   });
2. protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
   {
   optionsBuilder.UseLoggerFactory(loggerFactory)
   .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
   .UseSqlServer(@"Connection string");
   }
3. Then you will be see to logs in console with each and every line.

P.S : Please install Microsoft.Extensions.Loggin.Console nuget package

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all very much for your answers, but I solved it as follows

```
var result = context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(store_pocedure, queryParams);
```